# How to get the first elements of an array and then get the next few elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building my blog page for my website and I have a posts folder with markdown files of my blogs. I'm just figuring out a way to display all the blogs on a page, but I want to optimize it a bit so it doesn't try to load all blog posts at once but only the first 6 for example. And then when you click on a Load More button the next 6 get loaded and displayed.

This is the code I'm using to get the data from my blog posts:

```
async function getBlogPosts(n: number) {
  const files = fs.readdirSync('posts');

  const posts = files.slice(0, n).map((fileName) => {
    const slug = fileName.replace('.md', '');
    const readFile = fs.readFileSync(`posts/${fileName}`, 'utf-8');
    const { data: frontmatter } = matter(readFile);
    return {
      slug,
      frontmatter,
    };
  });

  return posts;
}
```

And then display the title of the posts:

```
export default async function Blogs() {
  const posts = await getBlogPosts(6);

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto flex">
      {posts.map(({ slug, frontmatter }) => (
        <div
          key={slug}
          className="m-2 flex flex-col overflow-hidden rounded-xl border border-gray-200 shadow-lg"
        >
          <Link href={`/blog/${slug}`}>
            <h3 className="p-4">{frontmatter.title}</h3>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How would one go about implementing this?

Because I think if I were to call `GetBlogPosts(12)` it would load 12 posts but also the first 6 which have already been loaded.

Comment: useState that increases by 6 when you click load more or use an offset to only show the next 6 your choise or use a combination of both and populate an array each time you fecth new blog posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is perfect.
Just implement pagination during slice method, increase page number as user clicks show more. and slice REQUIRED FILES data only.

Your code would look like this:

```
async function getBlogPosts(blogsPerPage:number, pageNumber:number) {
  const files = fs.readdirSync('posts');

  !IMPORTANT. sort files array here before slicing, so we wont get repeated posts...

  const posts = files.slice((pageNumber-1)* blogsPerPage,pageNumber*blogsPerPage).map((fileName) => {
    const slug = fileName.replace('.md', '');
    const readFile = fs.readFileSync(`posts/${fileName}`, 'utf-8');
    const { data: frontmatter } = matter(readFile);
    return {
      slug,
      frontmatter,
    };
  });

  return posts;
}
```

Now you can implement a state in your functional component and call this function somewhat like this:

```
export default async function Blogs() {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);

  const posts = await getBlogPosts(6,pageNumber);

  ......
}
```